# QUdpSocket and QThread

Tags: qt, sockets, qthread

As far as I understand from the documentation the QUdpSocket are async but, still, reading from the socket is performed on the UI thread when the signal readyRead() is emitted. Is that correct? Is that safe from the performance perspective? Should I read the socket's content in another thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything depends if you will have a lot of data to process. I've used the TCP socket with avarage transfer ~20mbps without blocking gui. Best thing would be check it yourself. I think you won't have to move socket to other thread

Comment: I see. So, in your opinion, when the signal readyRead() occurs is the UI/Main thread to exec the slot body?

Comment: It will be processed in ui thread if object will be constructed in this thread. But as I said you will have to check if your processing slot is not taking to much.

Comment: No it does not requrie much time but nervertheless I will be more happy if I could process it in another thread. If I move the socket object in this thread I will recive the readData signal?

Comment: remember that simply adding threads sometimes doesn't make your program run faster. Thread synchronisation may sometimes take more then processing data itself